# Flask_Sqlalchemy with multithreaded Apache. Sessions out of sync with database

Tags: multithreading, apache, flask, sqlalchemy

Background: Apache server using mod_wsgi to serve a Flask app using Flask_Sqlalchemy connecting to MySQL. This is a full stack application so it is nearly impossible to create a minimal example but I have tried.

My problem is that when I make some change that should modify the database subsequent requests don't always seem to reflect that change. For example if I create an object, then try to edit that same object, the edit will sometimes fail.

Most of the time if I create an object then go to the page listing all the objects, it will not show up on the list. Sometimes it will show up until I refresh, when it will disappear, and with another refresh it shows up again.

The same happens with edits. Example code:

```
bp = Blueprint('api_region', __name__, url_prefix='/app/region')
@bp.route('/rename/<int:region_id>/<string:name>', methods=['POST'])
def change_name(region_id, name):
    region = Region.query.get(region_id)
    try:
        region.name = name
    except AttributeError:
        abort(404)
    db.session.add(region)
    db.session.commit()
    return "Success"


@bp.route('/name/<int:region_id>/', methods=['GET'])
def get_name(region_id):
    region = Region.query.get(region_id)
    try:
        name = region.name
    except AttributeError:
        abort(404)

    return name
```

After object is created send a POST

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/app/region/rename/5/Europe
```

Then several GETs

```
curl -X GET https://example.com/app/region/name/5/
```

Sometimes, the GET will return the correct info, but every now and then it will return whatever it was before. Further example output https://pastebin.com/s8mqRHSR it happens at varying frequency but about one in 25 will fail, and it isn't always the "last" value either, when testing it seems to get 'stuck' at a certain value no matter how many times I change it up.

I am using the "dynamically bound" example of Flask_Sqlalchemy

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    ... snip ...
    return app
```

Which creates a `scoped_session` accessible in db.session.

Apache config is long and complicated but includes the line

```
WSGIDaemonProcess pixel processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}'
```

I can post more information if required.

Answer (score 0):

For reference if anyone finds this thread with the same issue, I fixed my problem.

My Flask App factory function had the line `app.app_context().push()` leftover from the early days when it was based off a Flask tutorial. Unfortunately snipped out of the example code otherwise it might have been spotted by someone. During a restructuring of the project this line was left out and the problem fixed itself. Not sure why or how this line would cause this issue, and only for some but not all requests.